# No Screen with name

Tags: python, kivy

All my program works up-to a point and I'm road blocked by it.

1. My program loads some starter screens in the main app.
2. Based on user input the program loads a completely different sub app.
3. Problem occurs when trying to change screens in the loaded sub app

Here is the code where the problem exists:

The .py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

chClass = ""

class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Home(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TitleScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ClassScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Warrior1(Screen):

    def GetChClass(self, ch):
        return ch

    def build(self):
        ExecuteW().run()

class Acrobat1(Screen):

    def GetChClass(self, ch):
        return ch

class Spell1(Screen):

    def GetChClass(self, ch):
        return ch

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WarriorStats(Screen):
    pass

class AcrobatStats(Screen):
    pass

class SpellCasterStats(Screen):
    pass

class ExecuteW(App):
    def build(self):
        return Home()

class RevengeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print chClass
    RevengeApp().run()
```

revenge.kv:

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import builder kivy.lang.Builder

<ScreenManage>
    transition: sm.FadeTransition()
    TitleScreen:
    ClassScreen:
    GameScreen:
    Warrior1:
    Acrobat1:
    Spell1:
    WarriorStats:

<TitleScreen>
    on_touch_down: app.root.current = 'Game'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'KnightArmor.jpg'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            color: 1,0,0,1
            text: "Warrior's Revenge"
        Label:
            color: 1,0,0,1
            text: "Click to Continue:"

<GameScreen>
    name: 'Game'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'KnightArmor.jpg'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: .5,.1
            text: "New Game"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Class'
        Button:
            size_hint: .5,.1
            text: "Load Game"

<ClassScreen>
    name: 'Class'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "Choose Your Path"
        Button:
            text: "Warrior"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Warrior1"
        Button:
            text: "Acrobat"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Acrobat1"
        Button:
            text: "Spell Caster"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Spell1"

<Warrior1>
    name: "Warrior1"
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "Warrior.jpg"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            font_size: "20sp"
            text: "Warrior's are physically strong"
            color: 0,.5,1,1
        Label:
            font_size: "20sp"
            text: "experts in hand to hand combat,"
            color: 0,.5,1,1
        Label:
            font_size: "20sp"
            text: "and knowledgeable in the ways of"
            color: 0,.5,1,1
        Label:
            font_size: "20sp"
            text: "arms and armor"
            color: 0,.5,1,1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: app.root.current = "Class"
            Button:
                name: "warrior_confirm"
                text: "Confirm"
                on_release: chClass = root.GetChClass('Warrior')
                on_release: root.build()
```

executew.kv:

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager

<Home>:
    transition: sm.FadeTransition()
    HomeScreen:
    WarriorStats:

<HomeScreen>
    name: 'Home'
    AnchorLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Stats"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'WStats'

<WarriorStats>
    name: 'WStats'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "Warrior.jpg"
```

The problem:
When clicking the stats button on the home screen in executew the WarriorStats screen named 'WStats' should be loaded,  but I get the error "no screen with name 'WStats'"

Comment: I figured it out... I add a function to my homescreen class in my py file switch(self): self.manager.current = 'WStats' then in my executew.kv -- on_release: root.switch() --- presto problem solved

Comment: I think you can post answers to your own question, so that your question is marked as solved and other people having the same problem can use your solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer that I figured out on my own

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def switch(self):
        self.manager.current = "WStats"
```

And in executew:

```
<HomeScreen>
    Button:
        text: "Stats"
        on_release: root.switch()
```